# Java-based Programs on My Computer can't Download Anything

Tags: java, eclipse, updates, download, minecraft

Ok this problem literally makes no sense to me, but here goes:
Java based programs that I use, eg. Minecraft, Eclipse, etc... are not able to update. The instant they start downloading an update, they freeze. With both, they will get about 3.5kb - 8kb down before it just freezes and won't download any more. It has been doing this for a couple months, so I don't have a restore point to before this problem was happening. I also have no idea what was installed around that time. Here is a screenshot of the processes that are still running (after I went through and stopped a bunch of random ones to see if that fixed anything) [image: task manager screenshot]

I don't know what to do, and it seems that reinstalling Windows is going to be too much of a hassle, because I have a couple programs from giveawayoftheday.com that I use often and the installs for those only work for a day, so I can't reinstall them after even though I still have the exe. 
Anyone have any ideas what could cause this?

I tried uninstalling anything sketchy looking, killing unknown processes, and turning off anti-virus and firewall.

Comment: is there a JVM update waiting to install?

Comment: Do you have multiple partitions on your box, with one partition running out of storage?  Are you sure that a firewall isn't blocking things, or Window's DEP?

Comment: do you know java? if so, try using a URL object to download something you know you can download elsewhere (in a browser) and see if it freezes up.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a jvm update waiting to install. Any way to check?

Comment: I only have 1 partition. I totally shut off firewall for public and private networks. I'll go look into the Windows stuff.
And for the URL object, ill try that and see what happens.

Comment: Using a URL object to download a file works fine. Downloaded an 80mb file no problem.

Answer (score 1):

So, Java applications you haven't wrote (Eclipse, Minecraft) can't download updates, but Java programs you write can (you've mentioned using a URL object to download an 80Mb file). It's not limited to one site, as Eclipse and Minecraft probably use different hosts.

We also can safely assume that the browser you *commonly* use, which appears to be Chrome, is also capable of downloading files.

So it seems likely a JVM or the application running on the JVM issue.

I would suggest one possible answer being in proxy settings; I would recommend checking to see if you've got proxy settings lurking around (given you've used the computer for sometime, it's possible you've used a proxy at some point). To test Eclipse specifically: open Eclipse goto Window > Preferences and type Proxy in the filter (top left corner). Network Connections should appear in the left menu. Under Active Provider, use Direct to prevent any proxy from being used. If its applied and now Eclipse updates work, yay. You can follow http://www.java.com/en/download/help/proxy_setup.xml to see how to generally correct Java's proxy settings.

Alternatively, you might be using a proxy for Chrome, that isn't being picked up by Eclipse. Chrome's proxy settings are found under Preferences > Under the Hood.